# Looping through shapefiles and lyr files to create multiple map documents using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-2.7

**Context**:

Using ArcGIS 10.3, Python 2.7.8.

I have *x* `.shp` and *y* `.lyr` files. I am trying to loop through the shapefiles folder and the `lyr` folder and to create *x* * *y* `.mxds` that each contains one shapefile and one .lyr file.

**Code**:

```
import os 
import arcpy

workspace = os.getcwd()

lyrFolder = workspace + '\\Lyr\\' 
shpFolder = workspace + '\\Shp\\'

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(workspace + 'empty.mxd') 
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

for shapefile in os.listdir(shpFolder):
  if shapefile.endswith(".shp"):
    shpLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(shpFolder + shapefile)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame,shpLayer)
    shpName = shpLayer.name

    for lyrFile in os.listdir(lyrFolder):
      if lyrFile.endswith(".lyr"):
        lyrLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyrFolder + lyrFile)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame,lyrLayer)
        lyrName = lyrLayer.name

        mxdName = shpName + "_" + lyrName
        mxd.saveACopy(mxdDir + mxdName + '.mxd')
```

**Expected result**:

I expected to create the map documents, each one containing 1 shapefile and 1 layer file, as suggested with this minimal example:

```
shapefiles = [shp1, shp2]
layerfiles = [lyr1, lyr2, lyr3, lyr4]

mxd = [mxd1, mxd2, mxd3, mxd4, mxd5, mxd6, mxd7, mxd8]

mxd1 = shp1 + lyr1
mxd2 = shp1 + lyr2
mxd3 = shp1 + lyr3
mxd4 = shp1 + lyr4

mxd5 = shp2 + lyr1
mxd6 = shp2 + lyr2
mxd7 = shp2 + lyr3
mxd8 = shp2 + lyr4
```

**Current result:**

The problem is that each time a new document is created, the previous file is also added, as below:

```
mxd1 = shp1 + lyr1
mxd2 = shp1 + lyr1 + lyr2
mxd3 = shp1 + lyr1 + lyr2 + lyr3
mxd4 = shp1 + lyr1 + lyr2 + lyr3 + lyr4

mxd5 = shp1 + shp2 + lyr1
mxd6 = shp1 + shp2 + lyr1 + lyr2
mxd7 = shp1 + shp2 + lyr1 + lyr2 + lyr3
mxd8 = shp1 + shp2 + lyr1 + lyr2 + lyr3 + lyr4
```

I have tried adding `os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM ArcMap.exe")` at the end of the second loop, but this only seems to solve the problem with the shapefiles: every new document is created with a single shapefile, but the `lyr` files still pile up till the last `mxd`.

Comment: Move your mxd and dataFrame variables inside the second for loop.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove previous shp layer in its own loop end, and lyr layer in its own loop end, after saving mxd.

(I used `glob` module. It gives full path of files matched given pattern)

```
import os
import arcpy
from glob import glob

workspace = os.getcwd()

lyrFolder = workspace + '/Lyr/' 
shpFolder = workspace + '/Shp/'

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(workspace + 'empty.mxd') 
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

shapefiles = glob(shpFolder + '*.shp') # [shp1_path, shp2_path, 0...]
lyr_files = glob(lyrFolder + '*.lyr')  # [lyr1_path, lyr2_path, 0...]

for shapefile in shapefiles:
    shpLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(shapefile)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, shpLayer)
    shpName = shpLayer.name

    for lyr_file in lyr_files:
        lyrLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(lyr_file)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame,lyrLayer)
        lyrName = lyrLayer.name

        mxdName = shpName + "_" + lyrName
        mxd.saveACopy(mxdDir + mxdName + '.mxd')

        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(dataFrame, lyrLayer) #######

    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(dataFrame, shpLayer) #######
```

Try that code. I didn't run all code myself. You may need small changes.

Comment: Is there any reason to use glob rather than arcpy.da.Walk here?  If I can get away with only importing one site package rather than multiple modules I try to.

Comment: No, Just habits. I like glob module.

Comment: I still upvoted. I asked because I suspect those new to ArcPy will find its da.Walk easier to learn than glob.

Comment: @PolyGeo, But, yes. `arcpy.da.Walk` is frequently more sensible.